# Problems killing a process with Python on Solaris

Tags: python, solaris, kill

I have a C++ program, called **C**, that is designed to shut down when it receives a SIGINT signal. I've written a Python program **P** that runs **C** as a subprocess.  I want **P** to stop **C**.  I tried 3 things and I'd like to know why some of them didn't work.

Attempt #1:

```
import subprocess
import signal
import os

p = subprocess.Popen(...)
...
os.killpg(p.pid, signal.SIGINT)
```

This code gives me the error

> OSError [Errno 3]: No such process`

even though the `p.pid` matches the `pid` displayed by [ps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ps_%28Unix%29).

Attempt #2:

```
import subprocess
import signal
import os

p = subprocess.Popen(...)
...
os.system('kill -SIGINT %u' % p.pid)
```

This gives me the error

> sh: kill: bad signal`

even though `kill -SIGINT <pid>` works from the terminal.

Attempt #3:

```
import subprocess
import signal
import os

p = subprocess.Popen(...)
...
os.system('kill -2 %u' % p.pid)
```

This works.

My question is, why didn't #1 and #2 work?

---

Edit: my original assumption was that since the documentation for `os.kill()` says `New in version 2.7: Windows support`, I thought that `os.kill()` is (a) first available in 2.7 and (b) works in Windows. After reading the answers below, I ran `os.kill()` on Solaris, which I should have done in the first place sorry, and it does work in 2.4.  Obviously, the documentation means that Windows support is new in 2.7.  Opps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first fails because `os.killpg` kills a process *group*, identified by its leader; you have a simple process, not a process group.  Try `os.kill` instead.  The second fails because the shell builtin `kill` understands symbolic signals, but the external command on Solaris doesn't (whereas on *BSD and Linux it does); use a numeric signal (`SIGINT` is `2` on Solaris, or use Python's predefined signal constants from the `signal` module).  That said, use `Popen`'s own interface instead as mentioned by someone else; don't reinvent the wheel, you're liable to create some corners.

Comment: The `/usr/bin/kill` external command on Solaris accepts symbolic names without the `SIG` prefix, so `kill -INT` should work.

Answer (score 1):

The [`Popen`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects) object has a [`kill()`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.kill) method that you can invoke as well as a [`terminate()`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.terminate) method and a generic [`send_signal()`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.send_signal) method.

I would use one of these rather than trying any of the out of band stuff you'd use with the `os` interface.  You've already got a handle to the process, you should use it!

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm using python 2.4 and all of those features were only added in python 2.6.

Comment: I just realized that when I rewrote the question, I accidentally removed the version information.  Sorry for the lack of clarity!